# Convert two dimensional array of double to string in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a simple way to convert `double[][]` to a String, showing all the values?

`Arrays.deepToString` does not work, because the inner values are `double[]`, which creates a compilation error:

```
 incompatible types: double[] cannot be converted to java.lang.Object[]
```

`Arrays.toString` will compile, but the resulting string is something like `[[D@64c25a62, [D@43e8f1c]`, which is not very useful.

I think the most concise solution is something like

```
Arrays.stream(a).
   map(Arrays::toString).
   collect(Collectors.joining("[", "," "]"))
```

which isn't exactly concise.

Is there something better?

*EDIT*

Actually, `Arrays.deepToString` does do what I want.  The error I was seeing that I thought mean it didn't work was from trying to pass a `double[]` to `deepToString`

Comment: Define concise. Your example is concise enough for a JVM to reach the intended result.

Comment: Your error suggests you are attempting to pass a `double[]` to `Arrays#deepToString`, but that should be passed to `Arrays#toString`. A `double[][]` will be correctly handled by `Arrays#deepToString` (tested against Java 8 and 17), where it will pass the nested arrays to `Array#toString`. Can you show an example array you are attempting this with?

Answer (score 2):

Note that `Arrays#deepToString` should only be used for multi-dimensional arrays when dealing with primitives. The error you got was because you attempted to pass a single-dimensional array of primitives, which should instead be sent to `Arrays#toString`.

```
double[] one = new double[]{4};
double[][] two = new double[][]{new double[]{1}, new double[]{2}, new double[]{3}};
String res;
res = Arrays.deepToString(two); //Good: #deepToString takes double[][]
res = Arrays.toString(one); //Good: #toString takes double[]
res = Arrays.deepToString(one); //compilation error: #deepToString cannot use double[]
```

(Above tested on Java 8 and 17).

Per the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) of `Arrays#deepToString`:

> If an element `e` is an array of a primitive type, it is converted to a string as by invoking the appropriate overloading of `Arrays.toString(e)`. If an element `e` is an array of a reference type, it is converted to a string as by invoking this method recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Use streams...

```
Double[][] test = {{1.0,1.2},{2.0,2.1}};
String s = Arrays.stream(test)       // Stream<Double[]>
          .flatMap(Arrays::stream)   // Stream<Double>
          .map(Object::toString)     // Stream<String>
          .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));
System.out.println(s);
```

`flatMap` will convert inner array to streams and catenate the streams into a single one.

If you want the same with `double` then convcert to the appropriate stream:

```
double[][] test2 = {{1.0,1.2},{2.0,2.1}};
System.out.println(test2);
String s = Arrays.stream(test2)            // Stream<double[]>
          .flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream) // DoubleStream
          .map(Object::toString)           // Stream<String>
          .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));
System.out.println(s);
```